# When is the estimated date that segregated witness gets fully implemented worldwide?

Tags: segregated-witness

I read the news recently that reviews had already been done and that the segregated witness program will be on deployment soon, so when is it expected to be fully adapted worldwide?  Or is there a target percent of implementation which can be considered completion of adaption?  Because I don't think all bitcoin stakeholders would rush to do such an upgrade considering potential risks in its implementation.

Comment: Hmmm, seems anyone does not have the idea of the target implementation date..  But this information is very important for VC investors.  Hope, somebody answers it, any smart estimate would be OK.